# Questions about specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags

1. [translation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) — good and popular tag.

   <sub><s>Still, it's usage guidance says it's about translation **into** Ukrainian, but at least one of the questions-about-translation-**from-Ukrainian** uses it too.</s></sub>

   <sub><s>Solutions:</s></sub>

   - <sub><s>(a) Rename it <sub>(by renaming I mean manually editing all 30 questions, I can do it)</sub> into [translation-into-ukr](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-into-ukr) (don't be afraid of the long name: users will use auto-complete anyway). The old tag would be disappear in one day of non-usage.</s></sub>
   - <sub><s>(b) Make it bidirectional officially by changing it's usage guidance (I like this idea less).</s></sub>
   - <sub><s>(c) Do nothing <sub>(just re-tag the one wrongly-tagged question)</sub>. In hope that it won't happen again (as the one wrongly-tagged question, probably, was asked before the guidance was created).</s></sub>

   *Solution to apply: leave it as is, but add smth like "а для пояснення значення українських слів/фраз використовуйте [word-meaning](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning)/`phrase-meaning`/`meaning`" to a usage-guidance.*
2. Should these tags in future become synonymous:

   - (a) [pronunciation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) and [phonetics](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonetics)?
   - (b) [ономастика](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) and [proper-names](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proper-names)?
   - (c) <sub><s>[history](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) and [language-history](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-history)?</s></sub> *Solution to apply: yes.*
   - (d) <sub><s>[learning](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning)=[навчання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f) and `language-learning`=[вивчення-мови](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8)?</s></sub> *Solution to apply: yes.*
   - (e) [word-difference](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-difference) and [word-interchangeability](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-interchangeability)?
   - (f) [borrowings](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borrowings) and [loan-words](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loan-words)?
   - (g) [orthography](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography)=[правопис](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81)=[орфографія](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%96%d1%8f)=[spelling](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling)? (Чисто формально це не одне й те саме, бо [orthography](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthography) — це будь-які правила правопису, в тому числі пунктуація, [орфографія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%8F) (принаймні в шкільному розумінні) включає в себе правила написання слів, переносу, капіталізації й разом-чи-окремо — але не пунктуацію, [spelling](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling) включає в себе саме написання слів, але не перенос чи капіталізацію та, тим більше, не пунктуацію, тобто orthography = правопис > орфографія > spelling — але чи потрібні відвідувачам всі ці тонкощі?)
3. <sub><s>About [synonym](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym) (or `synonyms` if positive [here](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/4)):</s></sub>

   - <sub><s>(a) Leave it as is.</s></sub>
   - <sub><s>(b) We can get rid of <s>[synonym](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym) (`synonyms`)</s> and introduce two more specific tags:</s></sub>

     - <sub><s>smth like `find-synonym` — 66.6% of current use-cases;</s></sub>
     - <sub><s>smth like `are-they-synonymous` as an alias → [word-difference](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-difference).</s></sub>

     <sub><s>In the (b) case user typing `syno` will be suggested by auto-completion to choose either `find-synonym`, or [word-difference](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-difference).</s></sub>

     *Solution to apply: leave it as is, but add smth like "а щодо різниці між словами треба використовувати інший тег.*
4. About [borrowings](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borrowings):

   - <sub><s>(a) Does such a term really exist? Isn't it a wrong calque of Ukrainain "запозичення" (i.e. [loan-words](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loan-words))? If it doesn't exist / is a wrong calque, should we manually replace it with [loan-words](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loan-words), or is it better just to make it an alias for [loan-words](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loan-words) later?</s></sub> *Of course, yes, sorry for a stupid question.*
   - (b) Should [this question](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/152/4) really use the [borrowings](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borrowings) tag? (IMHO, it's about [translation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation): "виключення" and "виняток" are translations, not borrowings; a borrowing is e.g. "екцепція" — or am I wrong?)
5. Does [transcription](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transcription) really apply [here](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/357/4)?
6. Do we need these tags:

   - <sub><s>(a) [linguistics](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics)? (this site is all about linguistics (although not necessary with experts), isn't it?)</s></sub> *Applied solution: left, changed tag guidance.*
   - (b) [speaking](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking)? (the same as above; [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags) and [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags) don't have `speaking`, but have `spoken-English`.)
   - (c) [learning](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning)=[навчання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f), [вивчення-мови](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8)? (the same as linguistics, I just can't get the purpose of this tag.)
   - (d) <sub><s>[cyrillic](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyrillic)? (we're mostly Cyrillic, aren't we? why we need a tag for that?)</s></sub> *Applied solution: deleted.*
   - (e) [phrase](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase)? (what's a purpose of this tag [here](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/54/4)? that's not about idioms. shouldn't it be just [translation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)?)
7. I understand these, but probably they have to get clearer names:

   - (a) [folk](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folk) — ______________?
   - <sub><s>(b) [latin](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin) — ______________?</s></sub> *Applied solution: renamed to [latin-script](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-script).*
8. [terminology](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) — в описі написано «для питань, пов'язаних з **перекладом** комп'ютерної та професійної термінології **на українську мову**» — чи це правильно? Адже людина просто хоче спитати про українську термінологію, наприклад, різницю між двома термінами. Ось [тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/420/4) в тезі [терміни](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d0%b8) людина, власне, так і робить — а я збирався зробити їх синонімами.

Comment: [Borrowing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/borrowing?s=t) "noun
1. the act of one who borrows.
**2. the process by which something, as a word or custom, is adopted or absorbed.
3. the result of such a process; something borrowed, as a foreign word or phrase or a custom.**

Comment: [Please make one thread for each tag or for each group of tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278104/are-general-tag-discussion-threads-ever-useful).

Comment: terminology - так, поки що переважно питання були про переклад, але у нас вже є тег переклад, не треба об'єднувати дві категорії в одному тегу. Най означає питання про будь-які терміни.

Comment: До речі - на сторінці синонімів вже чотири теги - варто щоб за них голосували: http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: @Artemix, просто bytebuster хотів спочатку вирішити, яка мова має бути основною перш ніж робити синоніми (бо невідомо, чи можна їх «розвернути»; що, по-моєму, логічно). Сам він за перші англійські. Але, коли я створив [ось це опитування](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/87/4) (як мені здавалося, через його прохання), відмовився там висловлювати свою думку і поставив його на закриття (мотивуючи тим, що текст занадто довгий і він не може його читати; що, по-моєму, якось не дуже). Відтоді питання про теджні синоніми трішки висить…

Comment: Я закрив це запитання, тому що воно містить багато окремих запитань. Можливі відповіді так чи інакше не зможуть відповісти одночасно на усі ці запитання. Натомість, у нас вже є декілька окремих дискусій стосовно окремих груп теґів.

Comment: @bytebuster, так, тут Ви праві, тут справді забагато запитань в 1.

Answer (score 3):

[translation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) не треба модифікувати. Запити по перекладу на інші мови вважаються оффтопіком - можна лише просити про пояснення значення слова. Тому навіть якщо цей тег буде використаний "навпаки" це питання швидше за все буде закрите.

[linguistics](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) можна залишити як тег для запитань щодо лінгвістики як науки - використання методів лінгвістики і т.і. А так, звичайно, це те саме що тег "програмування" на стековерфлоу.

У описі тега [синонім](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%96%d0%bc) можна написати що це тег для пошуку синонімів, а щодо різниці між словами треба використовувати інший тег.

[вивчення-мови](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8) - це питання про те як саме вчити мову: що читати, що слухати, які методи справді працюють, які ні (типу 25 кадру чи підкладання підручника під подушку).

UPD: [latin](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin) в контексті єдиного питання краще змінити на [latin-alphabet](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-alphabet), бо latin - це мова, а тут саме питання про алфавіт.

Comment: "translation" — мабуть в самому поясенння тегу слід буде написати, що це для перекладу **на** українську, а для пояснення значення українських слів/фраз використовуйте [tag:word-meaning]/`phrase-meaning`/`meaning`. В цілому згоден. [tag:latin] я змінив на [tag:latin-script] (мабуть, першим укр. еквівалентом буде `латинка`).